# Hiding Product Based on Product Type search.liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm trying to hide a product type from the in shop search tool. In the search.liquid file, I have included the following:

```
{%- for item in search.results -%}
            {%- if item.object_type == 'product' -%}
                {%- if product.type == "cpb_ordered" -%}
                    {%- assign displayProduct = false -%}
                {%- endif -%}
            {%- endif -%}
 {%- endfor -%}
```

But products with product type "cpb_ordered" are still appearing in search.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: please show the rest of the code.

Comment: I think you add an custom class based on type and hide the results, it is easy as compared to skip from listing.